# Discrete analogous to du Bois-Reymmond's lemma?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We say a function $\varphi:\mathbb Z^n\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ is **rapidily decreasing** if for for every $M\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$ there exists a constant $C_{\varphi, M}>0$ such that $$|\varphi(\xi)|\leq C_{\varphi, M}(1+|\xi|)^{-M},$$ for every $\xi\in\mathbb Z^n$. The constant $C_{\varphi, M}$ must not depend on $\xi$.

Let $\psi\in\mathscr{S}(\mathbb Z^n)$. Is it true that if $$\sum_{\xi\in\mathbb Z^n} \varphi(\xi)\psi(\xi)=0,$$ for every $\varphi\in\mathscr{S}(\mathbb Z^n)$ then $\psi=0$? This would be a discrete analogous to du Bois-Reymond's lemma.

Thanks

Comment: The characteristic functions $$\chi_{p} \colon \xi \mapsto \begin{cases} 1 &, \xi = p \\ 0 &, \xi \neq p\end{cases}$$ belong to $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{Z}^n)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Do I have to require $\psi\in\mathscr{S}(\mathbb Z^n)$? Can't I suppose $\psi$ is just a function on $\mathbb Z^n$?

Comment: Since you look at $$\sum_{\xi \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \varphi(\xi)\psi(\xi)$$ for all $\varphi \in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{Z}^n)$, $\psi$ can't be completely arbitrary, it must satisfy some growth condition. But it need not belong to $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{Z}^n)$, every function of polynomial growth is admissible. If you want to allow arbitrary $\psi$, you must restrict $\varphi$ to have compact support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding an alternative proof. We say $\varphi:\mathbb Z^n\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ is **slowling increasing** if there are $M\in\mathbb N_0$ and $C_M>0$ such that $$|\varphi(\xi)|\leq C_M(1+|\xi|)^M,$$ for every $\xi\in\mathbb Z^n$. We will denote by $\mathscr{S}^\prime(\mathbb Z^n)$ the vector space of these maps.

$\mathscr{S}(\mathbb Z^n)$ and $\mathscr{S}^\prime(\mathbb Z^n)$ are topological vector spaces and $\mathscr{S}^\prime(\mathbb Z^n)$ is isomorphic to the topological dual of $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb Z^n)$. The isomorphism is given by $T:\mathscr{S}^\prime(\mathbb Z^n)\longrightarrow (\mathscr{S}(\mathbb Z^n))^\prime$, $\psi\longmapsto T_\psi$, where $$\langle T_\psi, \varphi\rangle:=\sum_{\xi\in\mathbb Z^n} \varphi(\xi)\psi(\xi).$$
So the condition $$\sum_{\xi\in\mathbb Z^n} \varphi(\xi)\psi(\xi)=0,$$ for every $\varphi\in\mathscr{S}(\mathbb Z^n)$ means precisely $T(\psi)=T_\psi=0$. Since $T$ is injective $\psi=0$.